# Connecting over AWSIoTMQTTClient using only an access key id and secret access key with configureIAMCredentials

Tags: python, mqtt, amazon-iam, publish-subscribe, aws-iot

I'm trying to connect to **aws-iot** in order to subscribe to a topic. I would like use *configureIAMCredentials* as I saw in the [doc](https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-docs/sphinx/html/index.html#AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib.AWSIoTMQTTClient.configureIAMCredentials). Here my lambda file:

```
import boto3
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

def handler(event, _context):
    """Handle the lambda function."""
    aws_iot_endpoint = "xxxxxxx-ats.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    aws_port = 8883
    access_key = credentials.access_key
    secret_key = credentials.secret_key
    session_token = credentials.token

    aws_iot_mqtt.configureIAMCredentials(access_key, secret_key, session_token)
    aws_iot_mqtt.connect()
    

    aws_iot_mqtt.subscribe("pubsub/mqtt", 1, custom_callback)
```

I can't connect to iot, I have the error: **`connectTimeoutException`**.
I have checked the policy associated (*iot:connect permissions*). 
Can we connecting to iot in this way ? (without a root CA, using only an access key id and secret access key?)

Comment: Does the credentials that you've been using has access permissions for IoT? Also, Instead of using long term credentials, your Lambda may assume IAM role to perform IoT operations.

Comment: My Lambda assume role to perform IoT operation with the policy : `Action: - iot:*  Resource: "*" `  (*I know I should limit the policy to only the necessary permissions*). 

But I don't understand, the credentials that I use are temporary credentials that are generated with a boto3 session, so don't they automatically access permission for Iot ? how can I grant these permissions ?